# MPMoviePlayerController Not playing Local file

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, mpmovieplayercontroller

```
 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PTCL" ofType:@"mp4"];    
  NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:path];    
        MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];    
        [moviePlayerController.view setFrame:self.view.frame];
        [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view]; 
        moviePlayerController.controlStyle=MPMediaTypeAnyVideo;
        moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
        [moviePlayerController prepareToPlay];
        [moviePlayerController play];
```

---

```
 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PTCL" ofType:@"mp4"];   

path=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"file:/%@",path];   
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:path];

MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];

[moviePlayerController.view setFrame:self.view.frame];
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];

moviePlayerController.shouldAutoplay=YES;
moviePlayerController.controlStyle=MPMediaTypeAnyVideo;
moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
[moviePlayerController prepareToPlay];
[moviePlayerController play];
```

---

- file:///Users/utkal/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/F0B3AD63-7E46-4069-8845-8B0C05425CD2/CosMos.app/PTCL.mp4

I am getting this videURL path for first code

- file:///Users/utkal/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/F0B3AD63-7E46-4069-8845-8B0C05425CD2/CosMos.app/PTCL.mp4

I am getting this videURL path for second code.

I have alos use

```
NSURL *videoURL = [[NSURL alloc]init];
    videoURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"PTCL" withExtension:@"mp4"];
```

But my video player always show that file is loading and nothing happen.
I know some where I am doing mistake,but hard luck of mine.
please correct my mistake or tell me if any another way to play local video file.Please.

[image]

Comment: please try: NSURL * videoURL    =   [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

Comment: @Horst That doesn't work either. I'm having the same issue.

Comment: i have the same issue if yous olved this issue tell me.

Answer (score 4):

maybe is too late but i would try something like:

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *movieVC = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:file.location];
movieVC.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
movieVC.moviePlayer.fullscreen = YES;
movieVC.moviePlayer.allowsAirPlay = YES;
movieVC.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:movieVC];
```

notice the "movieVC.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;"

Comment: not too late for me ;) this actually solved it for me.

Answer (score 2):

I used this simple solution instead:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video" ofType:@"mp4"]];
MPMoviePlayerViewController* viewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:viewController];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"CapturedMedia"];
NSString *filePath = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/itemVideo.mp4"];
_moviePlayer =[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]];
[[_moviePlayer view] setFrame:[[self view] bounds]];
[[_moviePlayer moviePlayer] prepareToPlay];
[[_moviePlayer moviePlayer] setShouldAutoplay:YES];
[[_moviePlayer moviePlayer] setControlStyle:2];
[[_moviePlayer moviePlayer] setRepeatMode:MPMovieRepeatModeNone];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:_moviePlayer];
```

you set the property of the MPMoviePlayerViewController in .h file.

Answer (score 2):

`MPMoviePlayerController` is Deprecated Now. So I have used `AVPlayerViewController`. and written the following code:

```
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURL];
AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController = [AVPlayerViewController new];
playerViewController.player = player;
//[playerViewController.player play];//Used to Play On start
[self presentViewController:playerViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Please do not forget to import following frameworks:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AVKit/AVKit.h>
```

Hope this Helps..

Answer (score 0):

Your code for movie player is looking fine . There is something wrong  with the path . Just try to go to the path explicitly . And check whether that file is present there  or not. You can see following SO question for your reference :

[How to play video using MPMoviePlayerController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10814308/how-to-play-video-using-mpmovieplayercontroller)

Comment: Ya my file is their at path.

Answer (score 0):

A little late in the game but here's my complete code

In *.h

```
@interface v1SupportTable : UITableViewController
{
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer1;
}
```

In *.m

```
- (IBAction) playVideoBtn
{

        NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample_movie" ofType:@"mp4"]];
        NSLog(@"videoURL: %@ ...", videoURL);

        moviePlayer1 =[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];


        [[moviePlayer1 view] setFrame: [self.view bounds]];  // frame must match parent view
        [self.view addSubview: [moviePlayer1 view]];
        [moviePlayer1 setFullscreen:YES]; 


        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(doneButtonClicked) name:MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification object:nil];

        [moviePlayer1 play];


    }


    -(void)playMediaFinished:(NSNotification*)theNotification
    {

        moviePlayer1=[theNotification object];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayer1];
        [moviePlayer1.view removeFromSuperview];

        //when finished dimiss window
        [moviePlayer1 stop];
        [moviePlayer1.view removeFromSuperview];

    }

    -(void)doneButtonClicked
    {
        //[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
        [moviePlayer1 stop];
        [moviePlayer1.view removeFromSuperview];

    }
```